# python - regex to capture a number with comma or a dot unless between tokens

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I would like to replace a number with one of the following formats:
200,
200.99,
300,555
unless its between the <> tokens.
for example I would like to skip this:
<200>

This is what I came up with:

```
(?<!<)([\d,|.]+(?:\.\d{2})?)(?!>)
```

from testing it in regex101, I'm skipping only the first and last digit after < and before >.

I'm iterating over a text file line by line and I would like to replace all occurrences of the following examples:

```
200
200.00
200.000
```

with a  token, but if the line already have a number between <> then skip that line, to clarify, I would like to skip the following value in my line and not replaced by the regex:

```
<300>
```

this is the code I use:

```
current_line = re.sub("(?<!<)([\d,|.]+(?:\.\d{2})?)(?!>)", ' <num> ', current_line)
```

could you please assist?

Comment: can you please add some sample data ?

Comment: Would you like to replace `234`  in `Text here, then <234 and more here`?

Comment: I wrote the examples in the topic, I will clarify it more.

Comment: The issue with your regex, e.g. with the input `<200>`, is that the negative lookarounds can be satisfied by matching just the middle `0`, looking left/right to digits on both sides.

Comment: So, only `<>` with digits inside should not be replaced? Or any numbers  corresponding to `\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?` pattern?

Comment: So, you just need `(?<!\S)\d[\d,.]*(?:\.\d{2})?(?!\S)` or `(?<!\S)\d(?:[\d,.]*\d)?(?:\.\d{2})?(?!\S)`. In `re.findall`, also `(?:^|\s)(\d[\d,.]*(?:\.\d{2})?)(?!\S)` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an exact solution to your requirement, but if you change your negative lookarounds to positive lookarounds, which assert that the number is surrounded on both sides by either whitespace or starting/ending anchors, then you seem to get the behavior you want:

```
rx = r"(\s|^)([\d,|.]+(?:\.\d{2})?)(?=$|\s)"
s = "I would like to replace a number with one of the following formats: 200, 200.99, 300,555 unless its between the <> tokens. for example I would like to skip this: <200>"
print(re.findall(rx, s))

[(' ', '200,'), (' ', '200.99,'), (' ', '300,555')]
```

### Demo

 (courtesy of Wiktor)

One limitation of this is that it won't match a term such as `<234`, because the number is not surrounded on whitespace/anchors on both sides.  But, the pattern does correctly exclude numbers surrounded in tags.

Comment: [`(?<=^|\s)([\d,|.]+(?:\.\d{2})?)(?=$|\s)` does not work in Python](https://ideone.com/WeNC74). Do not blindly follow regex101, it is not a proof the pattern will work in the target environment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew We can ditch the negative lookbehind, behind `findall` is sophisticated enough to use capture groups.  Just don't capture the leading portion of the pattern.

Comment: the behavior is indeed what I want, but as already stated it does not work in python, any suggestion to modify it?

Comment: @Andreyn "does not work" is such a vague thing.  It works in Python, but does this answer really meet all your use cases?  Only you can answer that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the modified regex indeed worked, thanks!